# Coordinates in JavaScript vs Image on Mouse Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble for a personal website. 
I have 4 image on this website.

The goal , is to extend a bit one of the images when the cursor is on .

I wonder about the coding standard in this case. Shall I have a background image which contain all of the image, and display depending the position of the mouse with event.clientX and event.clientY? Or the best way is to put the 4 images on the html file with img and add a onmouseover ?

Please suggest me a better idea for this functionality

Comment: So you would like to change the appearance of the image if the user moves the mouse over the image? What is you question - do you want to know how to attach an onmouseover event to the image?

Comment: the main question is : shall i use event.clientX&event.clientY or shall i use <img onmouover>? and yes, the goal is to display the image a bit extends and , in the best world, change an image in black & white at the background into a colorfull image at the foreground.

Comment: For changing the image from black and white to a colored version you could change the image source. Either you use two images for each image (one for bw and one for the colored version). Or you combine them both into one image (fewer http requests) and move the image around (more code needed and could be brittle).
Do you need more pointers for changing the image source?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree.
i will use 2 images(b&w , colored) , i thinq the colored one will be in a div which will overwrite the b&w image, like this, i can hide this div with onmouseout it won't change the b&w first image . i'm looking for css attribut which could make the picture "coming to foreground" instead of appear/vanish with display or so.
ty for your code in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have 4 different images i would use onmouseover. So you do not have to calculate any coordinates. Working with coordinates / an imagemap is only needed if you have irregular shapes.

This  **[demo shows how to attach an event-handler to an image](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fox0EhFE8n5g4xQi2aBe?p=preview)** and set the border

This javascript

```
  function setStyle(that, setBorder) {    
    if(setBorder == 1){
        that.style.border = '4em solid red';        
        console.log(that.style.border);
    }
    else
        that.style.border = '4em solid green';
    return true;
  }
```

And this html

```
  <img src="http://plnkr.co/img/plunker.png" width="30px" 
        onmouseover="setStyle(this, 1);" 
        onmouseout="setStyle(this, 0);" /></a>
```

Comment: well , i'm trying to do so currently, but if you have an fiddlejs exemple or so , i will take it with pleasure.